# Get the filtered Data array from JavaScript sourced Data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

My dataTable version is 1.10.4.
I'm populating the datatable by passing the Javascript sourced data

```
var dataSet = [
    ['Trident', 'Internet Explorer 4.0', 'Win 95+', '4', 'X'],
    ['Trident', 'Internet Explorer 5.0', 'Win 95+', '5', 'C']
    //----
];



$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#demo').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>');

    $('#example').dataTable({
        "data": dataSet,
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Engine" },
            { "title": "Browser" },
            { "title": "Platform" },
            { "title": "Version", "class": "center" },
            { "title": "Grade", "class": "center" }
        ]
    });
});
```

Now I have a search input to filter the table based on the input.
I'm trying to get the filtered data that returns and rendering in the table.

For example, If the users search input is 'C' then i should get filtered data

var dataSet = [
        ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C']
    ];

Is there any standard way of getting filtered data in datatable?

if not I want to get the array on key up

```
$( "#searchInput").on( 'keyup change', function () {
    // get the filtered JavaScript data
});
```

Please refer to [JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/a8b3ttf7/6/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `search.dt` event for this (here assuming you have stored the instance of the dataTable in a `table` variable) :

```
$("#example").on('search.dt', function() {
    var filteredRows = table
                       .api()
                       .rows( {order:'index', search:'applied'} )
                       .data();

    for (var i=0; i<filteredRows.length; i++) {
        console.log(filteredRows[i]);
    };    
});
```

This will echo all the filtered rows out in the console in the same order as they are declared in your `dataSet` object :

```
["Gecko", "Firefox 3.0", "Win 2k+ / OSX.3+", "1.9", "A"]
["Gecko", "Camino 1.0", "OSX.2+", "1.8", "A"]
["Gecko", "Camino 1.5", "OSX.3+", "1.8", "A"]
["Gecko", "Netscape 7.2", "Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2", "1.7", "A"]
```

etc. **Note**, if you instantiate your table with `DataTable()` instead of `dataTable()` you will not need the `api()` reference.

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/fpbokb68/**

---

see **https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier** with examples of different ways to extract rows out of a dataTables instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example search for you;
you can delete button and add onchange to your area.

```
Search <input type="text" id="searchText">
<input type = "button" onClick="searchAndUpdate()">
```

This is function;

```
     function searchAndUpdate(){
        var searchText = $('#searchText').val();
        var resultTable = [];
        dataSet.forEach(function(element) {
            var objString = JSON.stringify(element);
            if(objString.indexOf(searchText)!=-1){
                resultTable.push(element);
            }
        });
        console.log(resultTable);

        //update your table
    }
```

**Note**: You have to update your table.
[Here EXAMPLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/a8b3ttf7/8/)